# Random varible and dicrete probability distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions

4 unbiased coins are tossed simultaneously. Obtain the probability distribution of the random variable 'numbers of head'.

Comment: The number of heads is the number of successes in four independent trials with probability $1/2$ of success on each trial, so the distribution is $\mathrm{Bin}(4,1/2)$. ${}\qquad{}$